# 7-segment display decoder truth table

Tags: digital-logic, 7segmentdisplay, decoder, truth-table

I am trying to make a decoder that can display all alphabetical letters on a 7-segment display. My inputs are ABCDE and the outputs are abcdefg

[image: truth table]

Is this the correct truth table for a circuit? If yes, what would its transformation to normal form look like?

I think it is correct, but I am struggling to simplify it.

Comment: @JRE Beat me to it, again.

Comment: If the right segments are driven, the truth table is correct. Checking this, though lengthy, is a trivial operation that you should be able to do yourself. As for solving, using a 5 variable K-map should be able to simplify it. You could also use the built-in functions of Logisim.

Comment: Use something like this (http://www.32x8.com/var5.html) for each segment.